# How to get DATEVALUE to recognize RSS 2 pubDate (RFC822)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

My formula contains an [RFC822](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) pubDate, e.g. as pulled from Google's [RSS2 Feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/MKuf).

```
=DATEVALUE("Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:00:00 +0000")
```

but it results in

```
Error
DATEVALUE parameter 'Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:00:00 +0000' cannot be parsed to date/time.
```

- According to [this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/33346427?hl=en), my locale should be set, but changing that can have other consequences in my sheet, which I do not want (FYI my current sheet locale is United States)
- According to this [stackexchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112318/what-date-formats-does-google-sheets-recognize), there is apparently no support for that

Is there a workaround to get my manually entered RFC822 dates recognized by DATEVALUE formula Google Sheets (I need this particular formula to perform various operations, so other than re-entering dates in compliant format, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you refer to this resource? https://sheetshelp.com/datevalue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using a REGEXREPLACE.

Example: A1 contains `Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:00:00 +0000`

In B1:

```
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\,(.*)\s+\+?[0-9]{4}.*$","$2")))
```

B1 now shows `44104`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following simpler formula

```
=DATEVALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\+.*",""))
```

[image: RFC822 dates to DATEVALUE in Google Sheets]

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.