# Setting up decimal separator, thousand separator and date in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-settings

Is there a way to change settings of decimal separator, thousand separator and date format in Google Sheets?

I would like to have:

1. dots for decimal,
2. space for thousand
3. date in format YYYY-MM-DD.

It is easy to set it up in Microsoft Excel. Can it be done in Google Sheets? I know that Google Sheets has an option to change locale. Is there any locale that has all the settings I want?

Comment: Complete list of formats [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106243) but I don't think any of them gives you space as thousand separator.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to go to:

- File
  → Settings
  → General
  → Locale
  → Change for a locale that uses a period as decimal separator instead of a comma
  (Canada English for example)

[image]

[image: select local google sheet]

Comment: It does not produce desired results but it is the best we can get.

Comment: *Locale. It's not Local. They didn't make a typo.

Comment: It sucks that this is the right answer. That is, the answer is good but it's annoying that you have to change this per spreadsheet. My computer, browser, Google are all in French but I happen to use period . for decimals...

Comment: Canada (English) sets it to period now, Sweden and Hungary to comma

Answer (score 6):

Try Mongolia for locale and format numbers as:

```
### ### ### ### ###.00
```

Comment: This is what I use but it messes up minus signs before small negative numbers. It puts all the spaces between the negative sign and the first number.