# Use comma as decimal separator in form based on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have seen this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113082/setting-up-decimal-separator-thousand-separator-and-date-in-google-spreadsheets) but my question is different. My sheet uses comma as decimal separator but when I publish it as a form, dot is used as the decimal separator.

**How do I change decimal separator in a form based on a Google Sheet?**

When viewing/editing the form I have looked under the ⚙️- and ⋮-menus but couldn't find anything that looked applicable there.

Interesting tidbit: I have enabled *response validation* in the form as well as *data validation* in the actual sheet. The condition is a value between 1,0 and 2,0 - but in the form these values aren't accepted, instead I have to enter 1.0 and 2.0 as limits.

If I enter 1,5 in the form it is rejected, I have to enter 1.5. But when I look in the sheet, 1.5 is rejected - I have to change it to 1,5 for it to be accepted.

Edit: Found this applicable [question](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12395085/decimal-separator-issue-between-google-forms-and-spreadsheet) with 84 upvotes but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Google Form.

One of the questions on the form requires input of a number between one (1) and two (2) (to one decimal place-max). You want the number to be entered in European number format ("**comma separator**" (,) instead of a "point separator" (.))

You have linked the form responses to a Google Spreadsheet. When the responses are shown in the spreadsheet you want the spreadsheet to recognise the form responses as a number in European number format.

---

It is not possible to assign a locale or language to a Google Form. In order to ensure that the value is input in European number format AND is recognised in the Google Spreadsheet as a number in European number format, the following is necessary:

1. apply a regular expression to the Form question
2. set the Spreadsheet Locale to a suitable European country

---

**Form Question: Response validation**

- click the "Kebab menu" and select "Response validation"
- select "Regular expression" from the dropdown menu
- in the 'pattern' column, paste  this expression: `^[1-2]+(\,[0-9]{1})?$`

---

**Spreadsheet Locale**

Check the `Locale` of your spreadsheet.

- File, Spreadsheet settings,
- Ensure that the locale is a country that uses the European number format.

---

**Spreadsheet output**

[image: spreadsheet]

---

**Examples of rejected Form input**

[image: failure01]
[image: failure02]
[image: failure03]