# Date comparison and DATEVALUE with dd.mm.YYYY. date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I'm using the custom date format for one of my columns, `dd.mm.YYYY.`. I want to compare that date to TODAY(), by using

```
+AND($D2 < TODAY())
```

where column D is the one with the dates in `dd.mm.YYYY.` format.

However, this comparison doesn't seem to be working the way I expect it to, because it returns `FALSE` for 07.06.2018 (the seventh of June).

Googling offered DATEVALUE in the way of solving my problem. So, I changed the test (spaces added here, for readability) to

```
+AND(DATEVALUE($D2) < TODAY())
```

This doesn't work as well, Google Sheets returns

`#VALUE Error - DATEVALUE parameter '01.01.2018' cannot be parsed to date/time.`

Finally, my question.

**How can I compare the date in custom format with today's date?** I want to do this without resorting to the use of substrings and casting parts of the date to integers.

Comment: I find it strange that it's not recognized / supported - according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), the format is in use in countries such as Belgium, Poland, Slovakia, most of the former USSR, Turkey, etc. But if that's the case (format not supported in Google Sheets), I guess I'll have to use the solution I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Set the spreadsheet locale setting to Bulgaria or to another country that u use a dot as date separator.

[image]

Related

- [Change Google Sheets default date format with other locale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103958/88163)